# Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals in svmclassify matlab

Tags: matlab, svm

I am using the matlab's svm classify function. My train and test data have the following dimensions:

```
>> size(TrainV)

ans =  

   99192         705

>> size(TestV)

ans =

246   705
```

I have a function that trains a one-versus-one classify with 10 classes (45 binary classifiers). The model can be trained by calling the function below:

```
Models = SVM_multitrain (TrainV(:, 2:end), TrainV(:, 1), 10);
```

I am sending the feature vectors (TrainV(:, 2:end)) and the labels (TrainV(:, 1)) and I am asking the Models to train the combination of couples for 45 classifiers (10). The function runs ok and I can have the following information after the training. For example, I will show the models for the 3rd and 45th binary classifiers.

```
> Models(3)

ans = 

      SupportVectors: [9x704 double]
               Alpha: [9x1 double]
                Bias: -2.3927 - 0.0001i
      KernelFunction: @linear_kernel
  KernelFunctionArgs: {}
          GroupNames: [20117x1 double]
SupportVectorIndices: [9x1 double]
           ScaleData: [1x1 struct]
       FigureHandles: []

>> Models(45)

ans = 

      SupportVectors: [10x704 double]
               Alpha: [10x1 double]
                Bias: -2.7245 + 0.0000i
      KernelFunction: @linear_kernel
  KernelFunctionArgs: {}
          GroupNames: [22087x1 double]
SupportVectorIndices: [10x1 double]
           ScaleData: [1x1 struct]
       FigureHandles: []
```

The problem is when I call the function to classify a feature vector, for example, for the first binary classifier.

```
>>         TestAttribBin = svmclassify(Models(1), TestV(:,2:end))
Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.

Error in svmclassify (line 140)
outclass = glevels(outclass(~unClassified),:);
```

What could be the problem? when I apply the same classification procedure to feature vectors extracted in another way this problem does not happen.

Comment: Is there any way you can upload some data reproducing the error and maybe code that can be run? The error sounds quite specific to me, so unless someone has encountered the exact same error before, I think nobody might be able to help you on that.

Comment: Could you please provide the output of models(1)?

Comment: Please also try 'dbstop if error' to stop when the error occurs and you can inspect sizes.

Comment: Immediately before the line that gives you the error, have you checked (as @g24l suggested) `size(unClassified)`, or any of the following: `class(unClassified)`, `sum(isnan(unClassified))`, `sum(isinf(unClassified))` ?

Comment: What does `outclass(~unClassified)` give? What is `outclass`? This is almost impossible to answer without a [mcve].

Comment: I realize here that my matrices of raining/testing are complex doube. Any problem with this?

Comment: @mad look you should just provide feedback on our comments first. That's just courtesy.

Comment: Hi all, the problem was in my feature vector generation. My feature vectors were complex. I already solved the problem, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The likely cause of this error is passing complex data to `svmclassify`. `svmclassify` only accepts real feature vectors. Indeed, passing a complex data to `svmclassify` results in `outclass` being complex and complex values cannot be used for indexing as stated by the error message.

One option may be to encode the imaginary part of your vector into the feature, for example by doubling the length of your feature vectors.

In fact the vast majority of machine learning models are based on the assumption of feature vectors being real eg. artificial neural net, regression trees, svm, etc. Although there might be some extensions in some case.

Comment: The error is about indices, not about features, right?

Comment: @AnderBiguri the root of the problem is the features being complex tho, which leads to complex indices later in svmclassify.

Comment: why all the negs? try to pass complex data to smvclassify and you'll get that message.

Comment: You should elaborate a bit more, because the answer you give looks like you completely misunderstood the question.

Comment: @AnderBiguri I'm pretty sure it's the right answer tho :) it just happens that passing complex data to svmclassify causes the error down the track (because it results in `outclass` being complex and complex cannot be used for indexing obviously).

Comment: I've tried to clarify my answer but if you think it can still be improved I am open to comments

Comment: The problem was in the feature vector generation. Some values were complex. They must be real. Thank you for your help.